# Plot value in range determined by MultiIndex

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib

I am importing some data from excel using `pd.read_excel(..., colum_index=[0,1])` to get a range where the values are valid

eg:

|  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19.5 | 20 | 4.3 | 4.6 | 4.8 |
| 20 | 21.5 | 4.5 | 4.5 | 4.6 |

The first 2 colums basically determine the range where the values in the data colums (A to C) are valid.

I am currenty struggling to plot it like this.

```
plt.axis([1, 80, 14, 32])
plt.imshow(df,cmap='rainbow',extent=(1, 80, 19, 32),vmin=2.0,vmax=6.3,origin="lower",aspect=100/8, interpolation='none')
```

This unfortunatly does not plot the values at the correct positions. The boxes are the wrong size and wrong position.

Currently it looks like this, which is close to what I want, but the rectangles are all the same size and at the wrong positions:

[image]

Comment: There’s a lot of things missing in your code: `colors`, `xaspect`, `xmin`, `xmax`, etc. Also can you please explain or show what the expected result is?

Comment: replaced variables with constants and added an image @Cimbali

Comment: It’s still unclear to me what you want @belst. What area should be coloured by each value? I see the index are bounds for the y axis, but how is the x axis defined?